# Why is sympy.arg() function not returning the expected output?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to extract the phase of a complex number in sympy but the `.arg()` method is not returning useful or expected results for even simple cases.

```
import sympy as s

A, theta = s.symbols('A theta', real = True)

expr = A*s.exp(theta*s.I)

angle = s.arg(expr)
print(angle) #Arg(A*exp(theta*I))
```

I expect the output to be just `theta` but it returns `Arg(A*exp(theta*I)` which is true but not all that helpful. why might this be happening for such a simple case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the argument to the function `arg` has to be an actual number. No symbols. You can see this from the following

```
from sympy import *
arg(1+2*I)
    Out[5]: atan(2)
A=symbols('A',real=True)
arg(A+2*I)
   Out[8]: arg(A + 2*I)
```

May be you can implement your own arg:

```
  from sympy import *
  A, theta = symbols('A theta', real = True)
  expr = A*exp(theta*I)
  simplify(simplify(atan(im(expr)/re(expr))),inverse=True)
```

Gives

```
   theta
```

ps. it is strange why this does not work

```
   simplify(atan(im(expr)/re(expr)),inverse=True)
   --->  atan(tan(theta))
```

But had to call `simplify` twice

Comment: This is the method that I ended up using. It still comes off as strange that the `.arg` function in a symbolic library can't handle symbols as inputs.